# whitespace removed in html tag

Tags: php, html, jbbcode

My current problem is with JBBCode library. When I use  tag ( I know it is depreceated ), my tag with parameter become  where x is the size.

My code :

```
 $font_size = '<font size="{option}">{param}</font>';
        $builder = new CodeDefinitionBuilder('size', $font_size);
        $builder->setUseOption(true)->setOptionValidator(new \JBBCode\validators\CssColorValidator());
        $this->definitions[] = $builder->build();
```

The result :

[image: image error]

So how can I force a whitespace in the tag ?

Comment: To me it looks like a bug in the `CodeDefinitionBuilder` class. Have you tried using double space or tab?

Comment: is `param` a space character?

Comment: Yes I tried double space or tab but same result